# How are these maximization problems same?

Tags: optimization, economics

This question is from Nicholson-Snyder's "Microeconomic Theory",page 200.([e-book here.](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~ebayrak/teaching/500F12/XYZ.pdf))

> Compare$$V^*(p_1,\dots,p_n,I_1,\dots,I_m)= \max_{x_1,…,x_n}
> \left[U(x_1,…,x_n)\text{ such that}\sum_{i\in r}p_ix_i\leq I_r;r=1,\dots,m\right]$$and$$ \max_{I_1,\dots,I_m}V^*\text{ such that }\sum_{r=1}^mI_r=I ,\tag {ii} $$ to the utility maximization problem $$\max_{x_i}U(x_1,\dots,x_n) \text{ such that } \sum_{i=1}^np_ix_i\leq I.\tag{iii}$$
>   Without any further restrictions, these two maximization processes will yield the same result; that is,
>   Equation ii is just a more complicated way of stating
>   Equation iii.

I can't understand why these are equivalent equations. I even can't understand the notations, what do variables beneath max mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are consumption of goods $1, \ldots, n$, respectively. Instead $I_1,\ldots,I_m$ is a partition of the budget $I$ for the $m$ groups of goods. For example with $n=3$ goods, $m=2$ groups and $I=10$ total budget, we could partition the goods into $\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}$ and decide to allocate $I_1 = 5$ "dollars" to the first group, and $I_2 = I - I_1 = 5$ dollars to the second. The general question is whether there is such a (non-trivial, i.e., $m > 1$) partition such that the demand function decomposes as in equation (i) (the important thing to note here is that demand for goods in group $r$ only depends on prices of other goods in group $r$ and budget $I_r$, but not on anything else).

To see that the two-stage maximation problem is equivalent to (iii), note that the constraints in the unnumbered equation imply the constraint in (iii) (why?). Therefore $V^*(p_1,\ldots,p_n,I_1,\ldots,I_m) \leq \max_{x_i}U(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, for any $I_1, \ldots, I_m$. (Note that the partition into $m$ groups is fixed throughout.)

As for the reverse inequality, suppose that $(x_1^*, \ldots, x_n^*)$ solves (iii). Without loss of generality (given the usual assumptions we make on $U$), the constraint in (iii) holds with equality. Let $I_r^* = \sum_{i\in r} p_ix_i^*$. Then $V^*(p_1,\ldots,p_n,I_1^*,\ldots,I_m^*) \geq U(x_1^*, \ldots, x_n^*)$, because the bundle $(x_1^*, \ldots, x_n^*)$ is feasible. Finally $\max_{I_1,\dots,I_m}V^* \geq V^*(p_1,\ldots,p_n,I_1^*,\ldots,I_m^*)$, and the constraint is satisfied with equality because of our previous assumption. (Of course both $\geq$ hold with equality, but we only needed this direction.)

Comment: Sir, is this the answer of "why":$$\sum_{r=1}^m\sum_{i\in r}p_ix_i= \sum_{i=1}^np_ix_i\leq\sum_{r=1}^mI_r=I?$$ Will you please explain why this implies $V^*(p_1,\ldots,p_n,I_1,\ldots,I_m) \leq \max_{x_i}U(x_1,\dots,x_n)$?

Comment: Sir, also, can't understand why $V^*(p_1,\ldots,p_n,I_1^*,\ldots,I_m^*) \geq U(x_1^*, \ldots, x_n^*)$ can be derived from $I_r^* = \sum_{i\in r} p_ix_i^*$?

Comment: Also, Sir in the original question posed by me, In the function $V^*(p_1,\dots,p_n,I_1,\dots,I_m)= \max_{x_1,…,x_n} 
\left[U(x_1,…,x_n)\text{ such that}\sum_{i\in r}p_ix_i\leq I_r;r=1,\dots,m\right]$, are we said to take all values of $r$ at once, that is do we have to find the biggest of $U$ among all the $r=1,\dots,m$ or do we have to take $r$ one by one?

Comment: I tried to ask in chatroom some of these, but they told me that they are confused! Please help me. I am really thankful to you as you have taken me up here and will be obliged if I am fully able to understand the answer. Sir, thanks for taking so much trouble for me.

Comment: I'm afraid you are confused as to what $r$ is. $r$ is just the generic name for a group of goods, much like $i$ is the generic good. In my example, the first group, $r = \{1,2\}$ is the first group, and $r = \{3\}$ is the second group. So we don't take "values of $r$", especially because the partition into $m$ groups is given!

Comment: @Sush The "why" is correct. It implies the inequality because we have shown that any allocation that satisfies the constraint in the unnumbered equation also satisfies the constraint in (iii), and we are maximizing the same function. Therefore the maximum value in (iii) cannot be smaller than the maximum value in the unnumbered equation. We show the reverse inequality by showing that the solution (_a_ solution) for (iii) also satisfies the unnumbered equation, for a particular choice of the budget allocations.